# Atribuir uma função a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, eu tenho um combobox, e eu quero que quando clicar em uma das opções do combo, ele faça alguma coisa. Eu queria saber como eu coloco uma variável ou método "vinculado" a opções do combo, por exemplo se eu clicasse na opção 1, ele me lista algo, se for na 2, ele só emiti um JOption pane (só um exemplo).

```
package teste;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Exemplo extends JFrame
{
    private String t;
    public Exemplo()
    {
        setTitle("Exemplo combo");
        setSize(500, 500);     
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);          


        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(null);
        add(jp);        
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItem("Opção 1");        
        combo.addItem("Opção 2");
        jp.add(combo);
        combo.setBounds(180, 200, 125, 30);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Exemplo ex = new Exemplo();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve criar e vincular um `Listener` de alteração da `JComboBox`:

```
class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
       if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          String value = event.getItem().toString();
          // faz algo conforme a opção selecionada
          if (value.equals("Opção 1")) {
             // faz algo se selecionou a opção 1
          }
       }
    }       
}
```

Para adicionar o `Listener` a `JComboBox`, faça:

```
addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener());
```

Comment: Desculpa, eu ainda não entendi muito bem, como você vai diferenciar opções diferentes ali ?

Comment: @Java pegando o item selecionado e fazendo uma condição, tipo `if(item == algumacoisa){//faz isso}else{ //faz aquilo}`

Comment: Entendi, obrigado aos 2 !

Comment: @Java Veja a resposta agora, pois adicionei mais detalhes.

Comment: @Java mas para algo simples, não ha necessidade de se criar uma classe a parte, pode usar classe anonima http://pastebin.com/6eTkYZ1c

Comment: Certo, e obrigado novamente !