# Selecionar item na JCombobox e retornar valor associado na JTextField no JPA

Tags: java, swing, jpa

Tento várias vezes em um form Swing fazer com que na hora de selecionar a opção na JCombobox apareça o valor do item da coluna da mesma linha na JTextField. Uma vez consegui fazer essa lógica porém foi com o JDBC e algumas funções que usei para este fim não mantive na interfaceDAO fazendo elas no próprio evento do JComboBox mouseClicked. Ficaram assim:

Classe MySQLProdutoDAO:

```js
public class MySQLProdutoDAO implements ProdutoDAO {

    private ConnectionFactory cf = null;

    public MySQLProdutoDAO(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.cf = cf;
    }
    
    
    /*  Métodos inserir, alterar e excluir */
    
    @Override
    public List<Produto> listar() {
        cf = new ConnectionFactory();
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().begin();
        //pedido = *, Pedido = nome da tabela
        Query consulta = cf.createEm().createQuery("select produto from Produto produto");
        List<Produto> produtos = consulta.getResultList();
        cf.createEm().getTransaction().commit();
        cf.close();
        return produtos;
    }
    
    public List<Produto> pesquisarPorNome(String nomeProduto){
        String jpql = "select nomeProduto from Produto p where nomeProduto = :name";
        List<Produto> produtos =  cf.createEm().createQuery(jpql).setParameter("name", nomeProduto).getResultList();
        return produtos;
    }
    /* tentei usar a lógica do select nomeProduto from Produto where nomeProduto = 'Produto A' para que ele exiba o nome do produto na coluna do banco e compare com o valor que o cliente escolheu; */
    
    public List receberValorUnitario(String nomeProduto){
        String jpql = "select valorUnitario from Produto p where nomeProduto = :produto";
        List valor = cf.createEm().createQuery(jpql).setParameter("produto", nomeProduto).getResultList();
        return valor;
    }
    /* e aqui para exibir o valor correspondente se a lógica acima produto selecionado == produto consultado no banco esteja correta retornando o respectivo valor em float */ 
    
}
```

E no formulário Swing
ViewPedidos:

```js
public class ViewPedidos extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    /*   Atributos, getters, setters */
    
    public ViewPedidos(DAOManager manager) throws DAOException {
        initComponents();
        atualizarTabela(manager);
        habilitarTextFieldEBotoes();
        List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
        clientes = manager.getClienteDAO().listar();
        produtos = manager.getProdutoDAO().listar();
        cbCodCliente.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(clientes.toArray()));
        cbNomeProduto.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(produtos.toArray()));
    }
    
    /* ....... */
    
    private void cbNomeProdutoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
      /* Exemplo realizado em JDBC */
         try {
        
        Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/loja","root","");
        Statement stm1 = con1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = stm1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE nomeProduto = '" + this.cbNomeProduto.getSelectedItem() + "'");
        while(rs1.next()){
            tfValor.setText(String.valueOf(rs1.getFloat("valorUnitario")));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }    
} 
    
 
}
```

Banco:

```js
+----+-------------+---------------+
| id | nomeProduto | valorUnitario |
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | Produto A   |         32.44 |
|  2 | Produto B   |          75.5 |
|  3 | Produto C   |         12.99 |
|  4 | Produto D   |         15.84 |
|  5 | Produto E   |          25.5 |
|  6 | Produto F   |          5.59 |
|  7 | Produto G   |          9.99 |
|  8 | Produto H   |         45.59 |
|  9 | Produto I   |         22.51 |
+----+-------------+---------------+
```

Eu já tentei pegar o valor selecionado pelo usuário, comparar com o campo do banco nomeProduto dai imprimir o valor na JTextField e mesmo assim não consegui. O que eu quero é fazer com que na hora que o usuário selecione o produto na JComboBox seja exibido o valor na JTextField ao lado (valor unitário) em JPA. Exemplo: Quando o "Produto A é selecionado na cbNomeProduto o valor exibido na JTextField seja 32.44 (float).

[image: Exemplo de funcionamento do evento]

Comment: Por favor, adicione um [mcve] para que seja possível executar o código e simular o problema.

Comment: Editei agora a minha publicação @diegofm, na função `cbNomeProdutoActionPerformed(evt)` eu escrevi a solução do problema em `JDBC` só que não sei como funcionaria um `resultSet()` no `JPA` (Ainda estou aprendendo a usar este framework) acabei criando aquelas duas funções acima: `pesquisarPorNome()` e `receberValorUnitario()` mas não estou conseguindo pensar em uma forma de trabalhar com elas no Swing.

Comment: O que você está querendo só será possivel se [**criar um ComboModel proprio**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105753/28595). E para pegar o item selecionado no combobox e fazer algo com ele, você precisa [**adicionar um evento de alterações**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189200/28595) neste combo. As duas respostas que linkei solucionam esta pergunta.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer este procedimento como você mencionou, quando eu criei esta JComboBox acabei criando ela através do Vincular > Elements e acho que isto acabou atrapalhando para manipular a JComboBox imagino.